# TFS PowerShell task not producing output when used with devenv

Tags: visual-studio-2017, tfsbuild, sql-server-data-tools

I can't use MSBuild to compile SSIS projects as it's not supported yet. Hence, 
I'm trying to use VS2017 devenv.exe to compile SSIS projects in my TFS (2017) task via PowerShell. I don't see any errors but neither I see the compiled output from dtproj files i.e. dtsx or ispac.

However, if I run the same powershell command manually on the build agent machine then it works fine and produces the output files. This is the command I'm trying:

```
$VsIdeExe = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe'
$BuildConfiguration = 'Development'
$PackageStagingLogsDirectory = "C:\temp\logs"

& "$VsIdeExe" "C:\temp\Source\SSIS\MyData.sln" /build "$BuildConfiguration" `
/log "$PackageStagingLogsDirectory\MyData.ide.log" `
/out "$PackageStagingLogsDirectory\MyData.sln.log"
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Which user account do you use when you manually run the script on the build agent? Is it same with the build agent service account? You can try runing the script during the build process with the account which works locally...

Comment: Yes, I'm using the same account.

Comment: I found an alternative and it works. So, instead of using *PowerShell task*, I used *Command line* task and it works like a charm! I don't know how the mechanics are different between these 2 tasks but my use case sufficed.

Comment: Well, that's an good experience, you could post the solution as an answer and accept it. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Comment: Will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative and it works. So, instead of using **PowerShell task**, I used **Command line task** and it works like a charm! I don't know how the mechanics are different between these 2 tasks but my use case sufficed.
Thanks!